# my button in HTML, is supposed to get tweets from Twitter Search API, but the button does not do anything.

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have read other answers to this question and/or similar questions, but I don't get why my button is not working. It does nothing. I have even looked at any JSON tutorial docs.

```
    <div style="padding:40px;margin-left:250px">
    <form>
       <input id="query" type="text" name="q" placeholder="word..." />
       <input id="start" type="button" value="Search" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div><ul id="tweet" padding:"20px"></ul></div>
```

This is the JSON code below. Got a bit confused on how to show the HTML above^

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function(){
       var twitterUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q="+
         $('#subject').val()+"&rpp=10&result_type=recent?";
       $.getJSON(twitterUrl, function(data) {
         $.each(data.results, function(i, item){
       $('#tweet').append('<ul>' + item.text + '</ul>');

     });
  });
});     
</script>
```

How do I make my button work? And also how do I get the tweet results to show up in a new window? So if you click button, it opens new window with results.

Comment: looks like you have a cross domain request issue

Comment: What do I do to sort that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `callback=?` parameter in the URL to the Twitter Search API.  Please see the documentation for JSONP and the Flickr example here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

Comment: I tried with the callback parameter as well. I read it on here. The button still does nothing.

Comment: also, I noticed you're using 'button' as the selector.  Try using the ID instead `#start`

Comment: here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FqD43/  There were two issues: 1) The $.each call was not closed. 2) I added the callback to the twitter URL.

Comment: Thanks. But I checked to see if it worked. But the tweets do not show up on the web page or in another blank webpage. How do I do that?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I found some code on here that worked. I just altered that depending on what I needed it to do. So thank you for helping me any-ways!!! @gmartellino